# IIS Server Subdomain Redirection

Tags: iis, web, http-status-code-404, subdomain, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012, with IIS 8 installed. I have multiple websites there. I also have the Default Website.

When I create a new website like www.abc.com and abc.com, it works fine. However, when a customer enters an invalid subdomain to abc.com (a subdomain definition that is not actually there), like xyz.abc.com, it automatically redirects to my Default Website which is a landing page.

Instead, I want to return a custom 404 page from IIS. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS should be taking care of that. If `xyz.abc.com` doesn't exist in the zone, no browser should be coming even close to IIS.

That is, unless you have a [wildcard record](https://startpage.com/do/search?query=dns+wildcard+subdomain) configured. It sounds like you might.

Give it a look.